# Modify endpoint to receive an XML file

Tags: java, xml, rest, servlets, endpoint

I'm using Postman to send an xml file as an attached file under the "form-data" option.
I'm adding a request header for "Content-Type" as "multipart/form-data"

[image]

But my endpoint is not getting the xml file. How can my endpoint receive the xml file?

```
@PUT
@Path("/{param1}/{param2}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response receiveXmlFile(List<Identifier> identifierList,
                                        @PathParam("param1") String param1,
                                        @PathParam("param2") String param2,

                                        @FormParam("xmlFile") File xmlFile)
)
{
    try {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(readXmlFile(xmlFile)).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).header("error", e.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to NOT send the `multipart/form-data` header from postman.

When sending the same request but without any headers, then my endpoint successfully received the file.